# jQuery tree view not loading

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I had created jQuery tree view with labels. A user can add or delete a node. I want textboxes instead of label. Please refer the code.

Node must be a textbox. All nodes must have textbox.

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Tree.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Tree" %>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tree Context Menu - jQuery EasyUI Demo</title>
  <%--  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../themes/default/easyui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../themes/icon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../demo.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>--%>

    <link href="CSS/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="CSS/easyui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="CSS/icon.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.easyui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <h2>Tree Context Menu</h2>
    <p>Right click on a node to display context menu.</p>
    <div style="margin:20px 0;"></div>
    <div class="easyui-panel" style="padding:5px">
        <ul id="tt" class="easyui-tree" data-options="
               url: 'tree_data1.json',
                method: 'get',
                animate: true,
                onContextMenu: function(e,node){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).tree('select',node.target);
                    $('#mm').menu('show',{
                        left: e.pageX,
                        top: e.pageY
                    });
                }
            "></ul>
    </div>
    <div id="mm" class="easyui-menu" style="width:120px;">
        <div onclick="append()" data-options="iconCls:'icon-add'">Append</div>
        <div onclick="removeit()" data-options="iconCls:'icon-remove'">Remove</div>
        <div class="menu-sep"></div>
        <div onclick="expand()">Expand</div>
       <div onclick="collapse()">Collapse</div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function append(){
            var t = $('#tt');
            var node = t.tree('getSelected');
            t.tree('append', {
                parent: (node?node.target:null),
                data: [{
                    text: 'new item1'
                },{
                    text: 'new item2'
               }]
           });
        }
        function removeit(){
            var node = $('#tt').tree('getSelected');
            $('#tt').tree('remove', node.target);
        }
        function collapse(){
            var node = $('#tt').tree('getSelected');
            $('#tt').tree('collapse',node.target);
        }
        function expand(){
            var node = $('#tt').tree('getSelected');
            $('#tt').tree('expand',node.target);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Json file:

```
[{
    "id":1,
    "text":"My Documents",
    "children":[{
        "id":11,
        "text":"Photos",
        "state":"closed",
        "children":[{
            "id":111,
            "text":"Friend"
        },{
            "id":112,
            "text":"Wife"
        },{
            "id":113,
            "text":"Company"
        }]
    },{
        "id":12,
        "text":"Program Files",
        "children":[{
            "id":121,
            "text":"Intel"
        },{
            "id":122,
            "text":"Java",
            "attributes":{
                "p1":"Custom Attribute1",
                "p2":"Custom Attribute2"
            }
        },{
            "id":123,
            "text":"Microsoft Office"
        },{
            "id":124,
            "text":"Games",
            "checked":true
        }]
    },{
        "id":13,
        "text":"index.html"
    },{
        "id":14,
        "text":"about.html"
    },{
        "id":15,
        "text":"welcome.html"
    }]
}]
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Comment: The tree view is created, but textboxes is not shown on each node. User can delete a node and add node.